# Null Pointer when maps component initializes in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2, forceclose

I've got an app that I've been working on for a while. The main activity shows a map using the GoogleMap class for Android (v2). Sometimes, not always, I'll get a null pointer when starting my app. Last time this happened, it stopped happening a day later with NO CHANGES to the code. I had a hunch that the map object wasn't available yet after looking that the logcat (posted below).

So I looked at this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map (Verify Map Availability section), and I'm already determining that the map object isn't null in onCreate.

Since this problem is intermittent, I can only guess that it has something to do with Google Services. I recently Force Stopped and cleared the data for the Google Services Framework app to try to get an update to 4.2.2 (sue me). Any thoughts - has anyone heard of this, or does anyone know how to get around it?

**EDIT:** This code now works again, exactly as you see here. I haven't changed anything.

**So my question is:** what could cause this sort of behaviour? I am checking the map object (the NPE on line 142 below) for being null in onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() using code directly from Google's Maps for Android v2 documentation.

**Included in onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() that shouldn't allow this...:**

```
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainMap))
                        .getMap();
    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    if (mMap != null) {
        // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
```

**Logcat:**

```
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at maps.ar.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at maps.y.h.a(Unknown Source)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at maps.y.au.a(Unknown Source)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at maps.y.ae.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IGoogleMapDelegate.java:83)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at com.tyler.ioio.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:142)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
02-14 13:33:03.190: E/AndroidRuntime(5448):     ... 11 more
```

**MainActivity:**

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // This verification should be done during onStart() because the system
    // calls this method when the user returns to the activity, which
    // ensures the desired location provider is enabled each time the
    // activity resumes from the stopped state.
    mLocMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    final boolean gpsEnabled = mLocMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        new EnableGpsDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(),
                "enableGpsDialog");
    }

    // Optimized code to go to location as fast as possible
    Location firstLoc = mLocMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateNewFix(getBetterLocation(firstLoc, currentLoc));
    // THIS IS LINE 142 : FORCE CLOSES
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Are you testing this on a device or an emulator? If you have an actual android device, you might have the same problem I ran into a while ago. My phone wouldn't actually close the app, so when I thought I was starting the app, it would really call onResume() and not onCreate(), which created problems with undeclared objects and such. this might not be even close, but it sounds like it might be your problem.

Comment: You problem starts somewhere around here : com.tyler.ioio.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java LINE # 142)  Can you post code showing your MainActivity.java file please?

Comment: @BenBenard It's a on a device. I have tried uninstalling the app in-between attempts to no avail.

Comment: What is line 142 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: @forgivegod I posted the code and commented line 142. The logcat says that the mMap object is not initialized, thus a null pointer. I've done checks for this though in onCreate() using code from Google [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map) (look for "Map Availability") and it's still having this problem. 

Funnily enough, it started working again today randomly a few hours later. I changed absolutely nothing - in fact I just ran the same code again.

Comment: @Code-Guru I posted line 142, as well as the proceeding part of the onStart() method.

Comment: mMap is null.  See if you can use the `findViewById` method again to get a valid reference to it

Comment: @forgivegod
I have added code that runs in onCreate() - is this not enough?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to modify your code like below;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

// This verification should be done during onStart() because the system
// calls this method when the user returns to the activity, which
// ensures the desired location provider is enabled each time the
// activity resumes from the stopped state.
    mLocMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    final boolean gpsEnabled = mLocMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!gpsEnabled) {
       new EnableGpsDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(),
            "enableGpsDialog");
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setup();

private void setup() {

// Optimized code to go to location as fast as possible
Location firstLoc = mLocMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
updateNewFix(getBetterLocation(firstLoc, currentLoc));
// THIS IS LINE 142 : FORCE CLOSES

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
```

I think that it's not proper to add toomany methods within onStart().

Comment: That's an idea. What am I aiming for with this exactly? Just cleaning up onStart() a bit?

Comment: @Tyler...Please read [this features](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) before making your Android app and then read [this procedures](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html) to implement Google Maps in your app. This document is the basic concept in Android.

Comment: Okay, sorry I haven't clearly explained what I'm looking for here. The code I've written works. I'm using it right now with no changes to onStart or onCreate. However, in some cases the app will force close with the error shown in the original question. When this happens, it happens for a few hours and then goes away. So far it has happened to me twice. I guess I'm having a hard time understanding how this would be part of the code and not a part of the underlying Google Services framework. This happens with both fresh installs (app starts with onCreate), and with onResume.